# Debuging es6 Proxy as property -> Internal error: illegal access

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

If I, in node.js 6.6, write (resp. have transpiled from TypeScript) a class like that:

```
 class Table {
    constructor(args) {
         this._rows = new Proxy({ test: 42 }, {});
    }
 }
```

And instantiate it like this:

```
var table = new Table();
```

When I debug in Visual Studio Code 1.2.1 when I want to watch the var table I always have

> Internal error: illegal access

written there, meaning I can not watch table or any of its properties.

The same thing works perfectly fine in Chrome.

So, why is that and what can I do about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Open a ticket on the VSCode issue tracker - this sounds like a bug.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those coming here first. It is indeed a bug this happens however Microsoft traced it to depreciated v8 debug code inside node.js itself. The workaround is to use `"type": "node2"` in your launch configuration file. This tells vscode to use the new debug protocol. Node 7+ is also recommended. Support for both is considered experimental as of vscode 1.10 and should used only if needed.

As of vscode 1.10 the "node2" code is being merged with "node". "type":"node2" is depreciated in favor of the "protocol" attribute. If set to "auto" the protocol will be switched automatically based on runtime determination. Setting to attribute to "inspector" simulates the effects of "node2" forcing the new debug protocol to be used. The default setting is equivalent to using "type":"node" in vscode 1.8.x, 1.9.x.

Comment: Almost one year later and this problem still happens. Thank you.